# How to set badge count in Oreo without showing a notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, badge

I used to show a number in app icon using [this library](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) as follows:

```
ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, numberToShow);
```

OneSignal also has same function in its Android SDK.

Now in Oreo, with the introduction of notification channels, things get complex to me. I can create a channel. Then, I can also create a notification as follows:

```
public static void createNotification(Context context, int numberToShow) {
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, context.getString(R.string.notification_channel_id))
            .setContentTitle("Dummy Title")
            .setContentText("Dummy content")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
            .setNumber(numberToShow)
            .build();
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

However, I have to show a notification with this solution, which I don't need and thus don't want. Is there any way in Oreo that I can achieve the same thing I have done previously, i.e. just showing 'notification dot' or a number attached to the app icon?

Comment: Sir,you need to use notification badge in oreo to replace that lib ??

Comment: @ALTegani I want to implement badge in oreo, have idea, in lower version badges github lib working bot in 8.0 and 8.1 not working need help....

Comment: Sir look for another https://android-arsenal.com/tag/140?sort=created

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no SDK-level support for showing numbers or other badges on launcher icons, other than the `Notification` scenario that you described.

Answer (score 5):

set the importance of the notification channel to

> IMPORTANCE_MIN

like `int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN;`
and then create the channel as -

```
NotificationChannel nChannel = new NotificationChannel
                    (channelId, title, importance);
```

This will the set the badge count(shown on the long press of the icon) without notifying the user about any notification in the system tray. ***Though the notification will be in the tray, but will not pop up and quietly reside there.***

Comment: It does not work. Even though I set IMPORTANCE_MIN the notification still show up on Action bar and Badge dot. Basically, I wanna it shows only by Badge dot ? Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes.. I have done that using the above.. Change the channel id for min.. And try again..

Comment: Thank ! It works in some case. I have just update my confirmation about your approach, Can you have a look at it ?

Comment: To display the badge, a notification has to have non-empty ContentTitle and/or ContentText, for example " ".

Comment: @miho39 showing only dot is not possible.. and makes sense as well. Dot is a way to notify the user that some notification for this app is awaiting your attention. If you set IMPORTANCE_MIN for a notification, the notification will not pop up and quietly reside in the system tray, after all other apps' notifications, but the dot will show on the app icon.